# Undefined method 'fetchCoursesByStudent'

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, doctrine

I'm making a project using PHP and Doctrine just for study purposes and I got an error that I've no idea what is causing it.

I made class called Student.php that has a Doctrine custom repository class that makes a custom fetch on my database. The thing is, during the execution of the code I got no errors, everything is fine with the code, it runs normally and works fine but the IDE says that my custom fetch method is Undefined even if it works well.

I'm using VS Code.

[Here's a print of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUX4a.png)

Here's what my custom method does:

```
<?php

namespace Alura\Doctrine\Repository;

use Alura\Doctrine\Entity\Student;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class StudentRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function fetchCoursesByStudent()
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
        $studentClass = Student::class;
        $dql = "SELECT s, p, c FROM $studentClass s JOIN s.phones p JOIN s.courses c";
        $query = $entityManager->createQuery($dql);
        return $query->getResult();
    }
}
```

Anyone knows what is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Your IDE has no idea what _type_ `$studendsRepository` is, so it can’t tell you which methods that might or might not have either.

Comment: @CBroe By reading your comment I though about add a line above `$studentsRepository` with a docblock `/** @var EntityRepository $studentsRepository */` that solved the problem. Maybe you could post this comment as an answer so I could give you the credits for helping me.